# find record if any of the value is match with the array element in the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection is like below:

```js
let data = [
    {
        "_id":"12345",
        "name":"Reshma",
        "skils":[
            "C",
            "React",
            "Java"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":"12346",
        "name":"Karishma",
        "skils":[
            "NodeJS",
            "Java",
            "Python"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":"12346",
        "name":"Karishma",
        "skils":[
            "JavaScript",
            "Python",
            "Angular"
        ]
    }
]
```

How d0 I find the record who is having skill in `Java` or `React`

Comment: Hey, are you using an ODM library for interacting with the DB like mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection_name.find({skills: {$in: ['Java', 'React']}})
```

[MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution allowing you to use a library.
You can check *lodash **find*** here.

https://lodash.com/docs/#find

*For your case, the following code should work*

args : ***data, skillsToMatch***

```
_.find(data, function(d) { 
       return _.find(d.skills,function(skill) {
                     return skillsToMatch.includes(skill)
             }); 
});
```

Comment: I would argue the best use is include loadash. Essentially you are including a whole library for something that is already supported by es6+ `Array.prototype#filter` . Furthermore the correct way would be to do it in the query it self (as @Simon) posted

Comment: I do rather agree with your statement but this is a candidate for a solution still if the author wishes to include the library. That said, we should always first look for solutions that do not involve external libraries as a good practice.